# How can I hide my personal information from public access when forming an LLC?

Tags: small-business, privacy

I am a US citizen want to create a company in the US that will not disclose my name or other personal information.

How can I create such an entity? Are some states better for this purpose than others?

Comment: The point of registering a company is that people interacting with it have a right to know who they are dealing with.

Comment: @DJClayworth I have no problem with accountability, but I desire privacy.

Comment: How can you be accountable to people if they don't know who you are?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance.

Comment: I posted here because this is the only relevant SE site for "Small Business", maybe someone with more rep can update the description for that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you hire a business attorney who can point you in the right direction and also be a representative for your business.

According to the [Law 4 Small Business blog](https://www.l4sb.com/blog/anonymous-llc/), New Mexico seems to have the best options for being anonymous.

> New Mexico is one of the few states that allows for truly anonymous
>   limited liability companies. An anonymous LLC means the state does not
>   maintain any records of ownership or management, and therefore has
>   nothing to disclose. In New Mexico, only the Articles of Organization
>   are submitted to the state, and the Articles requires only two names:
>   The organizer and the registered agent, neither of which need to be
>   the actual owner or manager of the anonymous LLC.